# Notify tester in TFS when assigned test changes

Tags: tfs, mtm

I use TFS 2013 Update 4 on premise.

I want my testers to receive an mail alert when one of the following conditions hit:

- A test (not test case) was assigned to a tester. (The value in column "Tester" changes)
- The state of a test assigned to a tester changes.

There is no alert-type which matches my criteria. I can't see a filter saying "when a test is assigned to [Me]".

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Did you create an alert?

Comment: I don't know what kind of alert to create. None of the existing ones matches my criterias.

Comment: Sorry, see my edit (line 1).

Answer (score 2):

1.you need to open the TFS project admin portal by using url for example
`http://alborzscm:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/project/_admin/_alerts/index`
or using `VisualStudio->Team->Project Alerts`

you should see below picture
[image]

2.Then `New` an alert, for `test` items choose from `WorkItem` categories in templates as below

[image]

3.Then customize the conditions as you wish as below
[image]

Comment: Thanks for posting but this won't work. It will inform me when a work item changes that I own. But if I go to test in TWA, then right click one there and choose assign to and then select my name, no alert will be generated that a test was assigned to me.

Comment: @sprinter252 you need to change the condition based on your requirement, it is just a sample

Comment: i know, but that's exactly my question. I guess there is no condition for test cases but I wanted to ensure I'm not missing something.

Comment: In the third picture I use it for `task` you can change it to any other type. If you describe your condition in a pseudo code style I can show you how to create the corresponding alert

Comment: But you can't change it to test case and select the assigned to field as the target. Sadly.

Answer (score 2):

From what I can tell, the answer is No, you cannot create an alert for Tester.  The Tester field is an attribute only on 'test points', which are not true 'work items', so you cannot query across them.  See this page, especially the comments:  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2012/01/17/faq-what-is-the-difference-between-assigned-to-and-tester-in-mtm.aspx

It is unfortunate, because it would be a very handy alert.